# CakePHP: Keep the same checkboxes checked after submit

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox, submit

How can I keep the same checkboxes checked after submit? All the other input fields on the form automatically keeps the values. I thought this would also go for checkboxes, but nope.

```
echo $this->Form->input('type_id', array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => array(
        '1' => 'Til salgs',
        '2' => 'Ønskes kjøpt',
        '3' => 'Gis bort'
    ),
    'div' => false,
    'label' => false
));
```

I believe this can be done in the controller, but how?

### Edit:

Since I posted this question I've changed to CakeDcs Search plugin, because I've gotten this to work with that before. Still... I can't get it to work this time.

Adding model and controller code:

#### AppController

```
 public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => '/',
        'loginRedirect' => '/login',
        'logoutRedirect' => '/',
        'authError' => 'Du må logge inn for å vise denne siden.',
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
    ),
    'Search.Prg'
);
public $presetVars = true; //Same as in model filterArgs(). For Search-plugin.
```

#### AdsController

```
public function view() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Localtrade Norway');
    $this->set('show_searchbar', true); //Shows searchbar div in view
    $this->log($this->request->data, 'debug');

    //Setting users home commune as default filter when the form is not submitted.
    $default_filter = array(
        'Ad.commune_id' => $this->Auth->user('User.commune_id')
    );

    $this->Prg->commonProcess(); //Search-plugin
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array_merge($default_filter, $this->Ad->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs)), //If Ad.commune_id is empty in second array, then the first will be used.
        'fields' => $this->Ad->setFields(),
        'limit' => 3
    );
    $this->set('res', $this->paginate());
}
```

#### Model

```
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');
public $filterArgs = array(
    'search_field' => array('type' => 'query', 'method' => 'filterSearchField'),
    'commune_id' => array('type' => 'value'),
    'type_id' => array('type' => 'int')
);

public function filterSearchField($data) {
    if (empty($data['search_field'])) {
        return array();
    }
    $str_filter = '%' . $data['search_field'] . '%';
    return array(
        'OR' => array(
            $this->alias . '.title LIKE' => $str_filter,
            $this->alias . '.description LIKE' => $str_filter,
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Sets the fields which will be returned by the search.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @return array Database table fields
 * @author Morten Flydahl
 * 
 */
public function setFields() {
    return array(
        'Ad.id',
        'Ad.title',
        'Ad.description',
        'Ad.price',
        'Ad.modified',
        'User.id',
        'User.first_name',
        'User.middle_name',
        'User.last_name',
        'User.link',
        'User.picture_url',
        'Commune.name',
        'Type.id',
        'Type.name'
    );
}
```

Comment: It does also work for checkboxes. At least if you do it right :) How does your controller code look like?

Comment: Also, how did you 'start' the form? Are you using 'post' or 'get'? In my experience, 'get' forms will not be automatically propagated in CakePHP

Comment: I've edited initial question with more code. The form is started with just $this->Form->create(array ('action' => 'view));

Comment: I suspect that this plugin loads the page two times, and on the second time $this->request->data['Ad]['type_id] is lost. This is based on debug-logging. But that does not explain why it can remember the value of the other input fields which are not checkboxes. I'm lost on this one. Probably a very simple solution, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set manually the `selected` option of the input, as an array with "*keys = values = intval(checkbox id)*"

I cannot explain why this format, but this is the only way I get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');

// Read the submitted value
$selected = $this->Form->value('User.Albums');

// Formats the value
if (empty($selected)) {
  $selected = array(); // avoid mess
} else {
  $selected = array_map('intval', $selected);
  $selected = array_combine ($selected, $selected);
}

// Renders the checkboxes
echo $this->Form->input('Albums',array(
  'type' => 'select',
  'multiple' => 'checkbox',
  'options' => $albums, // array ( (int)id => string(label), ... )
  'selected' => $selected, // array ( (int)id => (int)id, ... )
));
```

Hope this helps.
++

Comment: Thanks, but I do believe there's a cleaner way to do this. I've done it before, a loong time ago, but I can't seem to remember what I did. ;)

Comment: I didn't find a cleaner solution, so I went with yours. It works like a charm! Thank you! :)